# Bringing up Civilopedia for enemy units

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth, civ-beyond-earth-rising-tide

How do you bring up Civilopedia for enemy unit and units that don't belong to you?

By default you can right-click on the icon of a unit, and it brings up the Civilopedia nice and quick, but for almost everything else I have to press <kbd>F1</kbd> and manually type the name of the thing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to right-click (or left-click) on the icon you're selecting. If I for example wanted to find the Monument (Civ V) page, I would left click on the building icon (often a double click), and it will bring it up.

Comment: But how do I do this with enemy units?

Comment: Double right-click the picture on the pop-up when you select a unit

Comment: How can I select an enemy unit?

Comment: Click on the enemy unit on the screen as you would a city. Then follow my previous insructions

Comment: When I left click on an enemy unit it doesn't select them to where I can see there icon like I can with my own units.

Comment: How you worded it sounded confusing, but if I'm reading this right, you aren't able to see their location on the map by clicking on them. You should just have to left click on their location on the "gameboard" and that should bring up their little info thing. Make sure you aren't selecting any unit but it. It'll have the pic/art of the unit and from there you just have to right click on the pic